# HashiCorp Vault: Secret backends

Tags: hashicorp-vault

I'm a bit confused about some [hashicorp Vault](https://www.vaultproject.io/) concepts. We're intending to create an infrastructure using an IoC technology (vagrant and terraform). Also, we are using chef in order to provision machines.

We're trying to solve the problem of secret distribution. We're trying to understand Vault, nevertheless, there are some issues we don't quite figure out yet.

Why do I need several secret backends? I only want to spread credentials (mongo, elasticsearch, mysql), API tokens (AWS S3, Stripe) and CA certificates. Why might I need to use a special backend ([databases secret backend](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/secrets/databases/index.html), [AWS secret backend](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/secrets/aws/index.html), ...)

Comment: What do you mean by "I only want to spread credentials"?

Comment: I've not used the best works perhaps. Nevertheless, I'm using chef in order to be able to provision machines. According to each cookbook, i.e. `custom-nginx` I need to get a CA certificate and provide it into the machine, or in a `custom-wildfly` cookbook, I would need to get user and passwords...

Comment: The overview has a pretty clear explanation. If you just want to read/write things in whatever format as if you were writing to a file system you use the generic backend. If you want something that automatically generates a new key for aws every time you access the backend key then you use the aws backend. The specific backends "interact with the api" whereas the generic just read/writes whatever you give it. So in your case since you are storing things you already know the values for you can probably just use the generic backend

Comment: I've got it! Nevertheless (probably it's my fault), I don't quite figure out how which situations I would need to use those another backends(aws, ssh...) I don't quite to guess a real situation. Could you provide me any helping stuff scenario where I might use those backends (ssh for example)...

Answer (score 2):

In general the whole goal of vault is to make secrets easily changed, rotated, etc. So if/when a breach happens, it's trivial to reset everything to new secrets.  This is why we have the different backends, for things like postgres.  Every time you authenticate into vault and ask for PG connection information(i.e. user/pass/etc) it will create it for you, *on the fly* and turn it to auto-expire, etc.

The benefits of this approach is important.  One, the secrets last for only as long as they need to.  As soon as your program stops running(for whatever reason) the secrets should *go away*.  Also, every program gets a unique user/pass, so if there is a breach, you know exactly which application is responsible, you can easily restart it(on a new node/instance) and get your program running again(with new credentials, etc) While you then figure out how the breach happened, and get the breach fixed.

Plus vault has a very robust audit trail, so every secret access, every secret generation, etc is audited in a robust, verifiable way, which is really great when you do have a breach.

If you *NEED* these features or not, only you can figure out.  If you don't need, or are just starting out, you can use the generic secret backend and just store the user/pass there.